# GTKmm - unable to set fixed size to Gtk::Scale widget

Tags: resize, gtk, widget, gtkmm

I am writing a simple photo viewer in C++ using gtkmm and I can not sort out how to set widget size. In the bottom of main window I have `Gtk::Box` with 3 buttons, a label and a `Gtk::Scale` widget. I would like to set fixed size to `Gtk::Scale` widget and buttons, and give rest of the space to label. I have only managed to set fixed size to buttons, and divide extra space evenly between label and scale widgets, by adding widgets like this:

```
bottom_box->pack_start(*left_button, false, false);
bottom_box->pack_start(*right_button, false, false);
bottom_box->pack_start(*filename_label, true, true);
bottom_box->pack_start(*image_zoom, true, true);
bottom_box->pack_start(*fit_button, false, false);
```

When I try to set both `expand` and `fill` to false while adding `image_zoom` to `bottom_box`, the widget is way to small, and `set_size_request()` makes no change. Is there another way to do it?

Code responsible for creating the window is here (the rest is in the repository): https://github.com/jjkrol/ZPR/blob/master/src/gui.cpp

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted this out, I think the problem was associated with fact that I've called `set_size_request()` before adding `Gtk::Scale` to `Gtk::Box`.